# AS3 removeChild not working

Tags: flash, actionscript, removechild

I have an MC on stage using addChild @ frame 1. The MC is repeated using SetInterval to create a "marching ants" animation. I need to remove an MC at frame 100. I have tried a few variations of removeChild unsuccessfully.

Update - I have edited the code that will remove mc1 as well as the variable myInterval1

```
var removeTimer;    
clearInterval(myIntervalM1);
mc1.parent.removeChild(mc1);
//var mc1 was loaded @ frame 1 in the same manner as mc2
var mc2:arMC2;

function attachMC2 () {
        mc2 = new arMC2 ();
        mc2.x = 100;
        mc2.y = 100;
        addChild (mc2);

    }

var myIntervalM2:uint = setInterval (attachMC2, 500);
```

Comment: Performing `mc1.parent.removechild(mc1)` is redundant and may be the problem.  Try `removeChild(mc1)`

Comment: thx Sly. I moved the removeChild within the function. This removes the mc but the mc flashes because of the setInterval to make it repeat. Adding the clearInterval removes the Flashing but produces a background error.